# My mum spilt water on her laptop and now the shift key does not work

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, damage

A few months back my mum spilt water on her laptop. Not knowing much about what to do, she turned it back on a few hours later rather than let it dry. Since then the left shift key does not work.

I do not know if it is related but now the mousepad occasionally stops working.

Is there anyway i can fix this?

It is a Macbook PRO SnowLeopard

Comment: I suggest that once you get your computer repaired, you invest in a translucent keyboard cover to protect from spills and dirt. They are designed to stay in place all the time as you use your computer. http://goo.gl/vD7BS

Comment: @WheatWilliams Ditto! I would recommend the [Moshi Clearguard Keyboard Protector](http://store.moshimonde.com/clearguard-mb-us-layout.html).

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do now is to send it in for a checkup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an external Keyboard for a while, but this really needs repair/KB replacement.

This will not be covered by your warranty, and might be expensive. Your local apple store/reseller/repair agent can advise.

You might be able to get it fixed on your home insurance.

Source: Used to be an Apple Genius